# Structuring data for ticket sale analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, dataset, cross-section

I have some experience doing statistical analysis but most of it has been practiced using data formatted specifically for that type of regression/analysis. I now have my own data set but I'm at a loss as to structuring it and what analyses to perform (using R)

I have a data set of 1000+ ticket sales across 14 games with days prior to the event the ticket was purchased, ticket section (7 levels), opponent form, home team form, and opponent salary (as a proxy for away team quality) as independent variables. Here's a few example lines of the data I'm looking at.

```
Game    Section     Days.Prior  Cost    Away.Form   Home.Form   Opp.Salary
G2      C           1           38.52   5           2           17.41427
G3      ES          17          35.01   8           4           6.51609
G4      MR          2           79.95   3           4           22.13651
```

So within each game there are 7 levels of Section while Cost & DaysPrior are unique to each ticket.

I don't particularly care about a section effect, it's just there to explain variation in cost rather than the error term.

Where I get stumped is dealing with Away.Form, Home.Form, and Opp.Salary. I'm interested in the incremental effect of each on Cost, but there is no variation within each game. Every ticket within each game has the same Home/Away Form and Opp.Salary.

My questions are:

1) How do I structure this data for statistical analysis/Is it structured correctly as is?

2) What sort of model/analysis should I look at knowing the data structure for my variables of interest? (and if you have a link that provides a starting point or basic walk-through for that it would be much appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) How do I structure this data for statistical analysis/Is it structured correctly as is?**

I think the data is structured well enough already (as I can clearly differentiate different columns and also the number of rows in each column)

**2) What sort of model/analysis should I look at knowing the data structure for my variables of interest? (and if you have a link that provides a starting point or basic walk-through for that it would be much appreciated)**

Firstly, I do not think 14 games is enough data for predicting the team performance and/or form. I have done a similar research on cricket, where I had predicted the performance of a team depending on a bunch of features. So, for that, I had to take in 10 years of data into consideration. But, as a learning project, this data is good enough.

You can use neural networks for predicting the ticket cost, depending on the input variables, which include form, days prior and opposition salary.

You can also predict how fast the tickets would be sold out (days prior), depending on the type of teams playing, and also the probable price of the ticket given the demand.

So, the models which would be useful to you are:

[Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network): The features can be taken as the inputs and the result can be taken as the output of the network. Start with a single layer ANN

[Regression Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)

[Decision Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree): Decision trees are a wonderful model to estimate whether your ticket sales would be on the lower or on the greater side, depending on the value of the input variables. There are various models which you can construct out of them, but I suggest you start with the basic one.